# Flutter - The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I' just retreiving the profile information from the server, i ain't creating any model I'm directly updating the values but while fetching the data I'm getting an error as **Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.**

This is my json response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "record": {
        "user_id": "20",
        "user_name": null,
        "user_phone": null,
        "user_email": null
    }
}
```

And this is how i'm fetching from server and saving it.

```
 String userId = "";
 final response = await http.post(profileUrl, headers: headers, body: body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      print('Response in Profile Screen: ' + response.body);
      setState(() {
        username = jsonResponse['record']['user_id];
        print(username + "Userid");
      });
    }
```

And when I'm trying to print the userId i'm getting the error

Comment: `response` doesn't have the field you're trying to access. Why are you using POST for fetching? It should be GET.

Comment: The reason for the post request the project doesrequire that sort of request but i need to know if my approach is the right way I'm taking in the userid

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Can you post the correct code & what issue are you facing?

Comment: Hi, you try to get the data sure .? Not to post it ,,

Comment: I'm just posting the userId so that i can get the user details of that particular user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should assign *response.body* to *jsonResponse* before

```
  var jsonResponse = response.body;
  jsonResponse['record']['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ' in jsonResponse['record']['user_id];

`jsonResponse['record']['user_id->'<-]`

-><- signal what is missing

Can you confirm this is not the issue/You have it correct on your code?

Comment: It was my mistake while adding the question here, but even by adding ->'<- i;m getting the same error